# IOS Google+ Login fetch people list return null name property

Tags: objective-c, ios7, google-plus

I was using the following function to retrieve a list of people from user`s circles. However, when my app trying to access each people. It appears only the displayName is valid, the name property under person is null. and email property is also null. Anyone knows what I am missing ?

Thank you in advance for your help.

```
  for (GTLPlusPerson *person in _googlePeopleList) {
      NSString *name = person.displayName;
      NSString *firstName = person.name.givenName;
      NSString *lastName = person.name.familyName;
}

 (void)listPeople:(NSString *)collection {
    _googlePeopleList = nil;
    _googlePeopleImgList = nil;

    // 1. Create a |GTLQuery| object to list people that are visible to this
    // sample app.
    GTLQueryPlus *query = [GTLQueryPlus queryForPeopleListWithUserId:@"me"
                                                          collection:collection];

    // 2. Execute the query.
    [[[GPPSignIn sharedInstance] plusService] executeQuery:query
                           completionHandler:^(GTLServiceTicket *ticket,
                                     GTLPlusPeopleFeed *peopleFeed,
                                      NSError *err){
                                        _googlePeopleList = peopleFeed.items;
                                         }];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The response for [people.list](https://developers.google.com/+/api/latest/people/list) is a truncated [person resource](https://developers.google.com/+/api/latest/people#resource). [Try it](https://developers.google.com/+/api/latest/people/list#try-it) to see it live. If you want more details you'll have to query [people.get](https://developers.google.com/+/api/latest/people/get) individually.

```
{
   "kind": "plus#person",
   "etag": "\"RqKWnRU4WW46-6W3rWhLR9iFZQM/x6i0N_yYIL4lSYVVygDE4boxShc\"",
   "objectType": "page",
   "id": "111395306401981598462",
   "displayName": "Google Developers",
   "url": "https://plus.google.com/+GoogleDevelopers",
   "image": {
    "url": "https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/-Fgp8KFpgQqE/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAATSI/rnA__R9xehk/photo.jpg?sz=50"
   }
}
```

Comment: do you know the returned image, will that always be 50*50? could it be 80*80?

Comment: Look at the `sz=50` at the end of the image URL.

Comment: thank you so much! But sorry to bug you again, the email field is still null inside my GTLPlusPerson object, I do request additional scope for emails. any obvious mistake or omission off top of your head ? Thank you in advance.

Comment: You can't get other people's email addresses, only the currently authenticated persons.